# Lyapunov function for a non linear 3 dimensional system

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

How it is possible to find a Lyapunov function for the following system?
\begin{cases}
  \dot {x_1}=x_2+x_3 & \\
         \dot {x_2}=-\sin x_1-x_3 & \\
 \dot {x_3}=-\sin x_1+x_2 &
\end{cases}
I have tried with $V(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TPx+\int_0^{x_1} \sin{(s)} ds$ but I can't find out the right elements of P in order to obtain $\dot{V}<0$. Can you help me?

Comment: Consider a ball containing the origin such that $\sin x\approx x$

Comment: But I don't want to work with linearization ...I would like a lyapunov function...

Comment: Anyone can help me please??

Comment: What can you say about the equilibrium points of this system? Why do you think it can be asymptotically stable? Try $1/2x_2^2+1/2x_3^2+$ the integral term. Did you consider the linearized system (as mentioned above) to  see the behavior locally?

Comment: @Ilbant The linearized system about the origin does not give me informations about asymptotic stability, since the jacobian of the function f has an eigenvalue with real part equal to $0$...

Comment: @Ilbant the lyapunov function suggested by you has derivative identically $0$...I can only say that $x=0$ is stable but nothing about asymptotic stability

Comment: Yeah, because your system is not asymptotically stable...

Comment: First thing to note is that the system is at rest if $x_1(0)=\arcsin(x_2(0)), x_2(0)\in[-1,1],x_3(0)=-x_2(0)$. So global stability not possible.

Comment: @Ilbant So if the derivative is identically 0 this means that the system is not asymptotically stable?

Comment: this lyapunov function suggest only stability, not asymptotic stability. But I'm pretty sure you can only show stability.

Comment: @Ilbant Which is a possible way to show that the system is not asymptotically stable?

Answer (score 1):

The Lyapunov function (and also the first integral) of the system is
$$
V(x_1,x_2,x_3)= 1-\cos x_1+\frac12 x_2^2+\frac12 x_3^2.
$$
Indeed,
$$
\dot V(x_1,x_2,x_3)= \sin x_1\cdot x_1+x_2\dot x_2+x_3\dot x_3
$$
$$
= \sin x_1 \cdot (x_2+x_3)+x_2(-\sin x_1-x_3)+x_3(-\sin x_1+x_2)=0
$$
Since $V$ is positive definite and $\dot V$ is nonpositive, the origin is stable. It is not asymptotically stable because $V$ remains constant on the solutions of the system (and doesn't tend to zero).

Comment: But nothing excludes that I can't find out a better V that allows me to conclude that $x=0$ is asymptotically stable...if $\dot{V}=0$ I can say only that $x=0$ is stable but nothing about the asymptotic stability!

Comment: @pawel Let some solution $x(t)$ tend to zero as $t\to+\infty$. Then $\lim_{t\to+\infty}V(x(t))=V(0)=0$ (since $V$ and $x(t)$ are continuous). But this is impossible (except for the case $\forall t\in\mathbb R$ $V(x(t))=0$) because $V(x(t))$ is constant. We got a contradiction, thus, the origin is not asymptotically stable.

Comment: I disagree with you! Let a pendulum with friction you can choose $V(x)=(1-cosx_1)+\frac{1}{2}x_2^2$ and this allows you to conclude by krasowskii that $x=0$ is asymptotic stable

Comment: @pawel This is a different case. If you have friction, then $V$ is not a first integral/constant of motion. I.e. $\dot V$ is not identically equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

This system is not asymptotically stable. Near the origin we have $\sin x\approx x$ so the dynamics are practically

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2 + x_3\\
\dot x_2 = -x_1 - x_3\\
\dot x_3 = -x_1 + x_2
}
$$

or

$$
\cases{
x_1\dot x_1 = x_1x_2 + x_1x_3\\
x_2\dot x_2 = -x_1x_2 - x_2x_3\\
x_3\dot x_3 = -x_1x_3 + x_2x_3
}
$$

and after adding up

$$
x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 = C
$$

those orbits represent a center at the origin.

Comment: Sorry but when we obtain after linearization that x=0 is a center nothing we can say really about the asymptotic stability...a center for the linearized could be an unstable or stable focus for the original system...so why this system is not asympotically stable??

Comment: This system is not asymptotically stable because is is a center.

Comment: But it is a center of the linearized system..this means that the linearization does not help us on studying the stability of the origin!

Comment: @Cesareo What did you add up exactly to arrive at $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=C$ and what is $C$? I get $\dot{x}_1+\dot{x}_2+\dot{x}_3=2(x_2-x_1)$ and $x_1\dot{x}_1 + x_2 \dot{x}_2 + x_3\dot{x}_3 = 0$, how do you get from there to your last equation?

Comment: @SampleTime As $x_1\dot x_1 + x_2\dot x_2+x_3\dot x_3 = \frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2) = 0$ after integration we have $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=C$ with $C$ a constant $C\ge 0$.